# Solving system of non-linear equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

So I'm trying to find the stationary points for $$f(x,y,z) = 4x^2 + y^2 +2z^2 -8xyz$$

Setting the partial derivatives to zero leads to:

$$x-yz=0 \\ y-4xz=0\\z-2xy=0$$

Substiting $z=2xy$ into the first two equations to get $y(1-8x^2)=0$ and $x(1-2y^2)=0$. Which have the solution $y=0,x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}, x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$ and $x=0, y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Now how do I go about pairing my $x,y$ solutions?

Comment: The partial derivative equations are not linear.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Comment: I don't understand your actual question. What do you mean with pairing?

Comment: So I could combine and y solution with any x solution to get z value. But how do I check which combinations work?

Comment: A "system of equations" is actually a conjunction of equations. So what you did was the following. $$\begin{align} \begin{cases} x-yz&=0\\ y-4xz&=0\\ z-2xy&=0\end{cases}&\implies x-yz=0 \land y-4xz=0\land z-2xy=0\\ &\implies y(1-8x^2)=0\land x(1-2y^2)=0 \land z=2xy\\ &\implies \left(y=0\lor x=\pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 8}\right)\land \left(x=0\lor y=\pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)\land z=2xy\end{align}$$
From here you just use the well known logic rules (distributivity and what not). Basically I think the only thing you're missing is that a system of equations is a conjunction of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions:

- $y=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$ or $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$
- $x=0$ or $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Both of these must be true. That means that one of the conditions gives the value for $x$, while the other must give the value for $y$. For example, if $y=0$ then the first statement is true. Then $y\neq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y\neq-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so $x=0$ must be true to make the second statement true.

So $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is possible and gives you a possible value for $z$. In a similiar way, $(x,y)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$,$(x,y)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, $(x,y)=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(x,y)=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ are possible. Each of them gives you a value for $xy$ and hence for $z$.

Don't forget to check whether every solution indeed satisfies all equations in the system. You can do this by just calculating the given expressions with values for $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful: a solution of this system is always of the form $(x,y,z)$ so you should try to do this more structurally.

After the substitution of $z=2xy$ in the first equation, you get
$$x(1-2y^2) = 0$$
and from this, you have $x=0$ **or** $y=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ **or** $y=-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. This gives you three cases, check them all.

$\fbox{$x=0$}$

If $x=0$, then from the second equation you get $y=0$ and from the first you get $z=0$; this gives you a first stationary point: $\color{blue}{(0,0,0)}$.

Now check the other possibilities.

$\fbox{$y=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$}$

(...)

$\fbox{$y=-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$}$

(...)